# ZF2, PGSQL - how to determine current save path of file?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, zend-framework2

I would like to save some data from pgsql database to a csv file. The thing you also should know that I'm working at ZF2 Framework. So the code looks like this:

```
$adapter = $this->serviceMenager->get('db');
$adapter->query("Copy (Select * From data.my_data) To '/test.csv' With CSV;")->execute();
```

But while I'm trying to execute the code, I'm getting exception:

```
SQLSTATE[42501]: Insufficient privilege: 7 ERROR:  could not open file "/test.csv" for writing: Permission denied
```

That was the thing that I was expecting, because the only writing path is the public folder with privilages 777. But if I execute:

```
$adapter->query("Copy (Select * From data.my_data) To '/public/test.csv' With CSV;")->execute();
```

I'm getting exception:

```
SQLSTATE[58P01]: Undefined file: 7 ERROR:  could not open file "/public/test.csv" for writing: No such file or directory
```

How to determine where am I (I mean current path)? And how to properly set the path in the query to export my data?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be executed on PGSQL and not MYSQL as ins0 said.

The problem is almost what he stated though. You are trying to write to /test.csv, which means for PGSQL the root of the Unix server. You need to give the path you really want, and you can actually get the root of your app with [getcwd](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php).

Then your code will look like this:

```
$adapter = $this->serviceMenager->get('db');
$file = getcwd()."/public/test.csv";
$adapter->query("Copy (Select * From data.my_data) To '". $file ."' With CSV;")->execute();
```